# How does Angular know the types for dependency injection?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependencies

A simple question which I think might have a complex answer.

In Angular, I can specify a variable amount of arguments for a class constructor in my components. By adding a type to the parameter, Angular magically knows what instance should be passed in as a dependency.

```
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(private utils: Utils) {} // Angular knows its a Utils instance just by type
}
```

Even with injection tokens and other funky stuff Angular uses, I thought types were stripped at compile time and completely ignored. How is Angular able to know, just by type, what instance should be injected in?

Is it a webpack thing? Is there a TypeScript feature I am not aware of? What's going on?

In the Angular documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable#usage-notes) it says:

> Marking a class with @Injectable ensures that the compiler will generate the necessary metadata to create the class's dependencies when the class is injected.

Is this behavior defined in the Component decorator, or will it create metadata for every single class even when dependency injection isn't needed? What TypeScript feature is this?

Essentially, the best answer would be one that can help me incorporate dependency injection in to my own projects that **aren't Angular**.

Comment: basically the code is parsed and Utils is extracted and looked it up in the providers, if there is a match, use it.

Comment: The decorators you use for services, components, etc. add information to allow this - [_"Marking a class with `@Injectable` ensures that the compiler will generate the necessary metadata to create the class's dependencies when the class is injected."_](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable#usage-notes)

Comment: Thanks for the response guys, but I need some more information. How does TypeScript know when to generate this metadata? Does the Component decorator make that happen, or will it generate metadata for every class, even when not needed? What TypeScript feature is this? How can I use it in my own project?

Comment: I am going to amend my original question to have these points!

Comment: Any reason you want to use angular DI in your non-angular project? There are already some DI libraries you can use. If you look at the code of those libs, DI is not complex.

Comment: Not so much a case of wanting to use it in a project, but I am very curious about the inner-workings of some of my favorite libraries/frameworks! I put that line there to guide the direction of an answer.  I hope it encourages more detail and higher quality answers.

Comment: [emitDecoratorMetadata](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#emitDecoratorMetadata) compiler option and Reflection API is what Angular uses to achieve DI. You can read more about it [here](http://nicholasjohnson.com/blog/how-angular2-di-works-with-typescript/)

Comment: Oh that article looks great!!! Thanks @Siddhant I will give that a good read later.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize for not providing an answer sooner but I have gained quite a bit of experience with dependency injection since authoring the above question and can provide a high-level overview as to how it works.

Warning: as of writing, TypeScript decorators are at stage 3 of the ECMAScript proposal which is an important note because **decorators will be an official JS feature in the future** so the below answer will become invalidated as time goes on.

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators

Current implementations of decorators use the ['reflect-metadata'](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata) package made by Microsoft to provide the runtime information about types found during compile time.

This means that a class that uses a decorator provided by an appropriate dependency-injection package (i.e. [Tsyringe](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe), [TypeDI](https://github.com/typestack/typedi) or others) can use the statically analyzed type provided by reflection to correctly pass other class instances in to a DI enabled class using the decorator at runtime.

This works because TypeScript decorators wrap the constructor with a function after it has been compiled.

As type "tokens" are provided into the compiled code by the TypeScript compiler using reflection, instances can be retrieved from a central "container" (an object where all instances are stored in association with a token) and provided to constructors dynamically.